# ASP.NET MVC 5 - Repository use inside the view model?

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5

So I have a online shop. Each item has a productID (the abstract type of the product like pc, laptop, car, flower etc). So I have to get the product type inside my view. But I don't want to pass the product type manually each type in my controller. Is it a good idea if I use the category repository to match the product id with the product type inside my view model constructor?

Comment: Using an enum type for this kind of thing can be very handy.  It has the drawback of requiring to be synched with the db table but you more than make up for that in not having to hit the db every time.  Plus, type tables like that rarely change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I see a bit wrong about your idea is that you mix view-model with repository, which seems to be a bit messy. I think it'd be bit cleaner solution to load all required entities first and than map them into model in second step. In case of performance it might not change much (especially if you repository does some caching for example or if it utilizes lazy-loading) just that the code might be a bit cleaner:
1. get all required data from storage / cache
2. map the stuff to create view models